# Условные переменные

Tags: c, многопоточность, синхронизация, pthread

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

char password[] = "password";
char str[30];

pthread_cond_t wake_up;
pthread_cond_t wake_up1;
pthread_mutex_t mut;

void *enter_pass(void *a)
{
while(1)
{
    printf("Enter password:\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    scanf("%s", str);
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    pthread_cond_signal(&wake_up);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    pthread_cond_wait(&wake_up1, &mut);
}
}

void *check_pass(void *a)
{
while(1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    pthread_cond_wait(&wake_up, &mut);
    //pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    if(!strcmp(str , password)) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
            printf("true\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
        printf("Wrong password, try another\n");
        pthread_cond_signal(&wake_up1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
}
}

int main(void)
{
pthread_t thread1, thread2;
int rc;
long a;

pthread_mutex_init(&mut, NULL);
pthread_cond_init (&wake_up, NULL);
pthread_cond_init (&wake_up1, NULL);

rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, enter_pass, (void *)a);
if (rc) {
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
rc = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, check_pass, (void *)a);
if (rc) {
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
}
```

Да, так стало намного лучше (как я мог забыть), но если один раз ввести неправильно, то после второго ввода зависает.

Comment: "parameter name omitted". Ну и? Неужели из текста ошибки не понятно, в чем дело? В языке С не бывает неименованных параметров у фунцкий. Все параметры обязаны иметь явные имена.

Comment: Нет, всё ещё не то. Вы должны после сигнала отпустить мьютекс.

Comment: А для продолжения цикла вам нужна _вторая_ cond.var.

Comment: Ну и ждать первого сигнала надо тоже с захваченным мьютексом.

Comment: Окей, теперь вы создали потоки, но тут же выходите из программы. При этом всё, понятно, умирает. Вам надо дождаться завершения потоков. Используйте `pthread_join`.

Comment: Зря Вы редактируете вопрос, удаляя предыдущие сообщения. Сейчас (для не обладающих даром телепатии) он выглядит по крайней мере странно. И в любом случае всегда пишите, **что Вы ожидали увидеть** и что **реально** видите вместо этого.

Comment: А как тогда вставлять код? Все время заново? Ок, учту. Ожидал я увидеть ввод пароля, в случае, если неправильно - ввод заново. Вместо этого - первый раз ввожу неправильно - предлагает ввести заново, ввожу - зависает.

Comment: ВСЕМ СПАСИБО ЗА ОТВЕТЫ!

Answer (score 3):

- Во-первых, объекты `pthread_mutex_t` следует инициализировать перед использованием либо при помощи `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, либо при помощи `pthread_mutex_init`. Аналогично - `pthread_cond_t`.
- Во-вторых, поток, вызывающий `pthread_cond_wait`, обязан на момент этого вызова владеть соответствующим мьютексом. Я нигде у вас не вижу попыток захватить мьютекс `mut`, соответственно ваши вызовы `pthread_cond_wait` заведомо некорректны.

  "Традиционный" протокол использования `pthread_cond_wait` выглядит как

  ```
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
  ...
  pthread_cond_wait(&wake_up, &mut);
  ...
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
  ```
- В-третьих, функции потоков должны быть объявлены `void (void *)`, а не `void ()`.
- В-четвертых, как правильно заметил @VladD, завершение "основного" потока вашей программы (в котором выполняется `main`), тут же убивает весь процесс со всеми остальными потоками, не дожидаясь их завершения. Они даже квакнуть толком не успевают. Функция `main` должна ждать завершения ваших потоков через `pthread_join`.

Comment: Думаю, падение скорее вызвано доступом к неинициализированным переменным. `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` вряд ли состоит полностью из нулевых байт.

Comment: @VladD: Трудно сказать... Зависит от реализации. Я помню, что в "грязном" коде встречал синхронизационные примитивы, полагающиеся на нулевую инициализацию статических объектов, и такой код вроде даже "работал". Но спору нет, инициализировать синхронизационные примитивы, конечно же, надо явно.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, заглядываем в [документацию](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html):

> The `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_timedwait()` functions are used to block on a condition variable. They are called with `mutex` locked by the calling thread or undefined behaviour will result.

Идея condition variable заключается в том, что в *дополнение* к владению ресурсом вы хотите сигнализировать о наступлении события и *передать* владение этим самым ресурсом другому потому. В вашем случае ресурс — это строка пароля (которую, кстати, *нельзя* использовать из разных потоков, не защитившись мьютексом). Поэтому и логически без захвата мьютекса не обойтись.

---

На самом деле, вы были близко. Я переименовал переменные и подправил код.

Важное изменение: `pthread_cond_wait` будит только те потоки, которые *уже* дожидаются условия, а не те, которые *начнут* дожидаться его в будущем! Это означает, что мы обязаны обеспечить начало ожидания готовности пароля *до* отправки сигнала — а значит, до начала работы читающего пароль потока (поскольку этот поток сразу же захватывает мьютекс и не даёт проверяющему потоку начать ожидание!).

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

char password[] = "password";
char str[30];

pthread_cond_t have_password; // условие: есть новый пароль
pthread_cond_t need_next_password; // условие: нужен новый пароль
pthread_cond_t evaluator_started;  // условие: поток проверки паролей стартовал
pthread_mutex_t mut;

size_t input_password_no = 0;
size_t checked_password_no = 0;
int checker_started = 0;

void *enter_pass(void *a)
{
    size_t password_length;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter password:\n");
        // пользуемся разделяемыми данными - получили мьютекс
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        // scanf небезопасен
        fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
        // убираем финальный \n, если он есть
        password_length = strlen(str);
        if (password_length > 0 && str[password_length - 1] == '\n')
            str[password_length - 1] = '\0';
        // выставляем новый номер пароля, чтобы проверяющий поток
        // увидел, что он проснулся не просто так
        // поскольку мы обращаемся к разделяемой переменной, всё
        // происходит под мьютексом
        input_password_no++;
        // отправляем сигнал под мьютексом
        pthread_cond_signal(&have_password);
        // здесь можно было бы отпустить мьютекс, но нам тут же
        // понадобится взять его снова. так что можно сэкономить
        // на бесполезной операции
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        // ожидаем, пока не понадобится новый пароль
        // на время ожидания мьютекс будет автоматически отпущен
        while (input_password_no != checked_password_no)
            // на время ожидания мьютекс будет автоматически отпущен
            pthread_cond_wait(&need_next_password, &mut);
        // дождались - отпускаем мьютекс
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    }
}

void *check_pass(void *a)
{
    // получаем мьютекс...
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    // ... чтобы сигнализировать главному потоку о том, что мы стартовали
    checker_started = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&evaluator_started);
    // но мьютекс пока не отпускаем!
    while(1)
    {
        // вот здесь мы начали ждать, и отпустили мьютекс
        // при первом пробеге именно тут главный поток получит наконец управление
        // и запустит поток, вводящий данные
        // проверяем заодно, а не случайно ли мы проснулись
        while (input_password_no == checked_password_no)
            pthread_cond_wait(&have_password, &mut);
        // когда мы пришли сюда, у нас есть новый пароль
        // проверяем его под мьютексом...
        int password_ok = !strcmp(str, password);
        // и отпускаем мьютекс, как только нам больше не нужны разделяемые данные!
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
        // если пароль в порядке, завершаем работу потока
        if (password_ok)
        {
            printf("true\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Wrong password, try another\n");
        }
        // иначе снова берём мьютекс
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        // ... и сигнализируем, что нужен следующий пароль
        checked_password_no = input_password_no;
        pthread_cond_signal(&need_next_password);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t input_thread, check_thread;
    int rc;

    // инициализация
    pthread_mutex_init(&mut, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init (&have_password, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init (&need_next_password, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init (&evaluator_started, NULL);

    // теперь нам нужно дождаться момента, когда стартует поток проверки
    // захватываем мьютекс
    // поскольку мьютекс у нас, поток не сможет просигнализировать о старте
    // до того, как мы начнём слушать
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    // запускаем поток
    rc = pthread_create(&check_thread, NULL, check_pass, NULL);
    if (rc)
    {
        printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        // начинаем ждать сообщения о старте потока
        pthread_cond_wait(&evaluator_started, &mut);
        // только тут поток сможет получить мьютекс и просигнализировать
        // нам о старте
        // в этой точке поток проверки стартовал, и уже начал слушать
        // условие have_password (потому что раньше он не отпускал мьютекс,
        // а значит, мы не вернулись бы из wait)
    }
    // отпускаем мьютекс, он больше не нужен тут
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    // и запускаем вводящий поток
    rc = pthread_create(&input_thread, NULL, enter_pass, NULL);
    if (rc)
    {
        printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // пусть потоки себе перебрасываются условиями, мы ждём здесь окончания
    // работы проверяющего потока
    pthread_join(check_thread, NULL);
    // если проверяющий поток закончился, можно завершать программу
    // это прихлопнет и вводящий поток тоже (он должен сейчас ждать
    // запроса на следующий пароль).
    // если проверяющий поток 
}
```

Обратите внимание на борьбу со spurious wakeup'ами. Ожидание по condition variable может случайно завершиться преждевременно, так что нужно выставлять соответствующие флаги и проверять их.

Answer (score 1):

В вашей задаче scanf, который ждет ввода данных может служить "естественным синхронизатором" и тогда программа несколько упрощается.

```
char password[] = "password";
char str[30];

pthread_cond_t wake_up;
pthread_mutex_t mut;

void *enter_pass(void *a)
{

  while(1)
    {
      printf("Enter password:\n");
      scanf("%s", str);

      pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
      pthread_cond_signal(&wake_up);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    }
}

void *check_pass(void *a)
{
  while(1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    pthread_cond_wait(&wake_up, &mut);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    if(!strcmp(str , password)) {
      printf("true\n");
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    printf("Wrong password, try another\n");
  }
}


int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread1, thread2;

  pthread_mutex_init(&mut, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init (&wake_up, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, enter_pass, 0);
  pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, check_pass, 0);
  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
}
```

Теперь нужен только один mutex и одна condition variable.

Однако, полагаться на такую "синхронизацию" взаимодействия потоков нельзя. @VladD в своем ответе показал, как синхронизировать начало работы потоков из main.

А вот еще один способ "рукопожатия" без внешней синхронизации. Добавим пару переменных и простенькую функцию

```
int checker = 0, reader = 0;

void 
handshake (pthread_mutex_t *mutex, pthread_cond_t *cond, int *v1, int *v2)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
  *v1 = 1;
  while (!*v2)
    pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex);
  pthread_cond_signal(cond);
  *v2 = 0;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
}
```

А теперь вставим ее вызов в начало наших функций

```
void *enter_pass(void *a)
{
  handshake(&mut, &wake_up, &reader, &checker);
  ...
}
```

а в check_pass() переставим местами переменные

```
void *check_pass(void *a)
{
  handshake(&mut, &wake_up, &checker, &reader);
  ...
}
```

Все. Теперь функции будут ждать друг-друга и программу можно запускать, например, так

```
echo abc rireii password | ./a.out
```

Пока поток с check_pass не будет готов scanf не вызовется.

**UPDATE**

После обсуждения в комментариях "причесал" программку, теперь оба потока корректно завершаются, возвращаясь в main, в т.ч. по концу ввода (EOF), reader ждет пока checker не разрешит ему вводить следующий пароль (или скажет, что хватит читать -- пароль правильный). Для этого добавил 3 переменные (go, pass (продолжение работы reader) и check_it (продолжение работы checker)).

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


char password[] = "password";
char str[30];

pthread_cond_t wake_up;
pthread_mutex_t mut;
volatile int checker = 0, reader = 0, go = 1, pass = 0, check_it = 0;

void 
handshake (pthread_mutex_t *mutex, pthread_cond_t *cond, 
           volatile int *v1, volatile int *v2)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
  *v1 = 1;
  while (!*v2)
    pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex);
  pthread_cond_signal(cond);
  *v2 = 0;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
}

void *enter_pass(void *a)
{
  handshake(&mut, &wake_up, &reader, &checker);
  puts("reader ok");

  while (go) {
    printf("Enter password:\n");
    int rc = scanf("%s", str);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    if (rc != 1)
      go = 0;
    check_it = 1; // send to checker signal "password ready..."
    pthread_cond_signal(&wake_up);
    pass = 0;     // prepair to wait checker's signal
    while (!pass) // wait checker send "continue..." (set pass = 1)
      pthread_cond_wait(&wake_up, &mut); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut); 
  }

  puts("reader fin");
}

void *check_pass(void *a)
{
  handshake(&mut, &wake_up, &checker, &reader);
  puts("checker ready");

  while (go) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    while(!check_it) // wait scanf in reader done (and reader set check_it = 1)
      pthread_cond_wait(&wake_up, &mut);
    check_it = 0;    // reset variable for next iteration

    if (go) {
      if(!strcmp(str , password)) {
        printf("true\n");
        go = 0;
      }
      else
        puts("Wrong password, try another");
    }

    pass = 1;  // send to reader signal "continue..."
    pthread_cond_signal(&wake_up);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut); 
  }

  puts("checker fin");
}



int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  pthread_t thread1, thread2;

  pthread_mutex_init(&mut, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init (&wake_up, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, enter_pass, 0);
  pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, check_pass, 0);
  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

  return puts("End"), fclose(stdout) == EOF;
}
```

Обратите внимание на атрибуты `volatile` у переменных, совместно используемых в разных потоках (они же и в аргументах handshake()).
Кстати, функция handshake -- **одноразовая**, т.е. потоки могут безопасно ей воспользоваться только при внешней (до их запуска) инициализации переменных checker и reader.

Если что-то неясно, спрашивайте, постараюсь объяснить.

Comment: У вас вроде бы в `check_pass` два раза подряд отпускается мьютекс.

Comment: А идея с `handshake` классная, украду её себе.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, сейчас выкину.

Comment: Ещё одна вещь (простите за занудство): `enter_pass` начинает вводить новый пароль потенциально до окончания проверки в другом потоке (и даже если этот пароль не будет фактически нужен).

Comment: @VladD, да, пожалуй это неправильно. Надо бы сделать ожидание ответа от check_pass через какую нибудь разделяемую переменную аналогично handshake и выходить из цикла по успешному паролю.

Comment: @noobster, обновил ответ, пример программы с синхронизацие шагов reader/checker

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, вам _не_ нужно `volatile`, т. к. весь доступ к этим переменным находится под мьютексом.

Comment: @VladD, наверное это может зависеть от компилятора. В gcc независимо от мьютексов не нужно (достаточно обращений к любой внешней функции, чтобы компилятор перечитывал внешние переменные из памяти) / Все, отбываю до понеедльника.

Comment: Ну, если компилятор (компоновщик) заинлайнит вызов, он _может_ видеть внутренности функции. Насколько я понимаю, поддержка pthreads означает, что вся необходимая магия (запрет отложенной записи через `pthread_mutex_unlock`, правильный memory barrier) обязана выполняться компилятором. То есть для него `pthreads_cond_wait` не _просто какая-то_ внешняя функция, а _специальная_ внешняя функция.

Comment: Хороших выходных!

Comment: То есть, в случае pthreads _все_ компиляторы обязаны вести себя как gcc.